# How to query drupal timefield data

Tags: php, drupal, time, drupal-7

Scenario:

We have a bunch of events, each event has a date field, and a separate time field that has a start and end value. I'm trying to build a module pulls in the next event that hasn't ended yet. Also, if there are more than one events on that day, we need to pull all of them.

My main problem is figuring out how to construct the values that I need to query that time field with, it seems to be stored is a format that I'm not familiar with, e.g. the value 4:30PM is stored as 59400. I can't find any documentation that specifies how to convert that value back and forth.

Any Drupal gurus / php gurus out there know what that conversion is?

Thanks, 
Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time (59400) is in seconds.
So, 59400/(60x60) = 16.5 = 4:30.

You can use the gmdate() php function:

```
gmdate("H:i", 59400);
```

Comment: Thanks man. To clarify a little further, it represents seconds since midnight.